# Is there a way to bind an item height using its index in the ItemsSource collection?

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I have a WPF control which has a listbox which is bound to observable collection.

the collection change a lot so tracking of its items index is a bit of a pain.

I need items in the listbox to be different heights according to their position/index on the screen.

```
Items[0].Height = 30; 
Items[1].Height = 25;
Items[2...n].Height = 20;
```

so the height of the items does not depend on the data.

I do not want to add dep property to the data item and try to calculate the data item index in the collection.

**I want to make listbox items to be aware of their indexes in the listbox ItemSource.**

*P.S. I can live with any items control (not necessarily listbox)*

**can it be done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're not using alternating row styles, you can hijack the alternation indexing for this. Here's a simple example that just displays the index along with each item's ToString:

```
<ListBox AlternationCount="99999" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Interesting.. Let me try. I will need a converter to create correct heights using the index. lets see if it will be quick enough. thank you

Comment: it almost worked! unfortunately the item 0 sometime displays 99998. everything else worked fine!